# Show Query in ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

```
SELECT 
    /*MATERIAL COST USD*/
    Material_Cost_Gbp * Material_Rate_Usd AS Material Cost Usd,
    
    /*MATERIAL COST BURDEN & SCRAP*/
    ((Material_Cost_Gbp * Material_Rate_Usd) * Material_Rate_Burden / 100)
        + ((Material_Cost_Gbp * Material_Rate_Usd) * Material_Rate_Scrap / 100)
        + (Material_Cost_Gbp * Material_Rate_Usd) AS Material Cost Burden & Scrap,
    
    /*MATERIAL COST PER PCS*/
    (((Material_Cost_Gbp * Material_Rate_Usd) * Material_Rate_Burden / 100)
        + ((Material_Cost_Gbp * Material_Rate_Usd) * Material_Rate_Scrap / 100)
        + (Material_Cost_Gbp * Material_Rate_Usd)) / Qty_Bar AS Material Cost per Pcs
FROM 
    dbo.Nmaterial
```

How can I insert this query code for display in web page using ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: Are you trying to ask you wanna display query result on view?

Comment: hello.. i want show the query in view page.. but i don't know how to make this in asp.net mvc 5.. i already have the query and how to make that or implement I'm creating new table using 'AS' showing in summary page.

Comment: yes @YatFeiLeong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have installed EF in your project.
First you need to create a View Model. For example:

```
public class TestVM
{
    public string EX1 { get; set; }
    public decimal EX2 { get; set; }
    public decimal EX3 { get; set; }
}
```

After that you can map your query to the view model property

```
        IncendoContext db = new IncendoContext(); // This is your own db context

        string _sqlcom = "Select a as EX1, b as EX2, c as EX3 from Table";

        List<TestVM> result = db.Database.SqlQuery<TestVM>(_sqlcom).ToList();

        return View(result);
```

Note that the property name has to be similar to your query as xxxxx
You need to change your query, you cannot have any space (after as) to define your query property name anyway.
Under the View, just may just simply list the property

```
@model IEnumerable<Incendo.Web.ViewModel.TestVM>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test123";
}

<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td> @item.EX1</td>
    <td>@item.EX2</td>
    <td>@item.EX3</td>
</tr>


}
</table>
```

Please define your own namespace property. Leave a message if you have any problem.